# How to translate “Friendship means little when it’s convenient” to latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In the recent John Wick movie there’s a quote saying title question.

I’ve come up with
“Amicitia parum valet cum commodo est”

Looking to see if I got it right or what it needs to be changed.

Comment: It does not quite carry the authority of a John Wick movie, but note that there's also: *Amicus certus in re incerta cernitur* (Ennius apud Ciceronem: Laelius de Amicita 1, 64).